# Windows WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) aws s3 cp command slows drastically when downloading to external drive, while other methods aren't affected

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-s3

Was hoping someone might be able to explain whats going on here:

I have been trying to download large files from AWS S3 to my local computer.

Using standard:

`aws s3 cp s3://my-big-file.file ./`

I'm getting ~70 MiB/s

When downloading to an external drive, I suddenly drop to around ~10 Mib/s.

`aws s3 cp s3://my-big-file.file /mtn/d/`

At first, I thought ok this makes sense, the external drive is throttling me.

However, using [S3Browser](https://www.s3browser.com), downloading to the external drive, I'm getting ~70 MiB/s.

This is frustrating because I'm trying to automate downloads of projects... and can't with the S3Browser.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I went ahead and installed AWS CLI for Powershell.

The aws s3 cp command is also as fast as S3Browser, so it seems there is some bottleneck with WSL.
For now I plan to just write a script in powershell, but I'm still curious to know whats the cause of this!

Comment: How are you measuring speed?  You'll need to measure the time to complete the task, not a point-in-time measurement.  It's possible S3Browser is aggressively caching data during the download, and will take a long time to flush data to the drive when it's done transferring.

Comment: The CLI and S3Browser will display their speeds, I've run some tests with smaller files, and there doesn't seem to be any odd load times at the end of transfers.

Comment: Oh.  WSL.  Yeah, there are [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) there.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks for sharing that. I'm not alone!